# How do I run a login system and comment system that will also display the username when posting in one server/port?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on a project that needs a login/registration system which than goes to a comment system. I want to be able to run that comment system and than display the username of the person who posted the comment. The problem is I have a socket.io comment system that runs express. At the same time the login system uses express. Resulting to the fact that I can only run one of them at a time. In my case the login system is working fine but the comment system cannot post or display any comments.

Below: I have only just started to learn nodejs so, there might several errors. I also have two server files one for the login system and one for the comment system.
[this is how I have configured the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMag0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). – Please clarify your question and ask a specific question (refer to the given links for guidance on how to improve your question).

Comment: I have not used socket.io for awhile, but you can use both express end point and socket.io. try the getting start example from socket.io ref https://socket.io/get-started/chat/